# Looping an image inside a div and loop the div after it will contain 4 images

Tags: php, codeigniter

currently i have this structure

```
<div class="col">
   img1
   img2
   img3
   img4

</div>

<div class="col">
   img1
   img2
   img3
   img4

</div>
```

then when i tried to loop it

i got this results

> img[0] 
>   
>   
>       img[1] 
>   
>   
>       img[2]

how can i achieve this structure

```
<div class ="col"[0]>
    img[0]
    img[1]
    img[2]
    img[3]
</div>
<div class ="col"[1]>
    img[0]
    img[1]
    img[2]
    img[3]
</div>
```

Loop code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($images as $k => $v){
    $imagesrc ='graph.facebook.com/'.$v['fbid'].'/picture';; 
?> 

<div class="col" >
    <img [<?php echo $k; ?>] src="<?php echo $imagesrc; ?>" width="29px" height="31px" alt="name">
</div> 

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: You should really include your loop code and any other applicable code, it well yield a better (more complete) answer

Comment: <?php  foreach ($images as $k => $v){
         $imagesrc ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$v['fbid'].'/picture';
?>
        <div class="col" >
           <img [<?php echo $k; ?>] src="<?php echo $imagesrc; ?>" width="29px" height="31px" alt="name">
                                    
         </div>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop you want to add a `<br>` or `<p>` after each image.

Example inside loop

```
$counter = 0;
$firstTime = true;
$column = 0;

 <?php foreach ($images as $k => $v): 
  $imagesrc ='graph.facebook.com/'.$v['fbid'].'/picture'; 

  if ($firstTime) {
     echo '<div class="col'.$column.'" >';
     $firstTime = false;
  }

  if ($counter > 3) {
    echo '</div>';
    $column++;
    echo '<div class="col'.$column.'" >';
    $counter = 0;
  } ?>

  <img src="<?php echo $imagesrc; ?>" width="29px" height="31px" alt="name"> 
  <?php $counter++; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: and how can the br help? i want is that it must fill the div with 4 images then after create another div if the div dont have 4 images then it will not create another div

Comment: so you just need to move the div outside of for loop

Comment: done that the image already loop inside the div so how can i create another div when there are 4 images inside it

Comment: i don't understand your problem. where do you want to create the other div

Comment: why problem is how can i execute that if the div as already 4 images in it it will create a new div again of course the image is loop with foreach

Comment: do you have multiple loops? i don't see how it will create a new div again if it's created outside of the for loop and close after it

Comment: I only want 4 <img> per <div class="col"></div>. So when it hits 4 I want it to generate a new <div class="col"></div> and to continue on until it reaches the end of all the images.

Comment: i know i just posted the new code. I think i understand your problem now. This will limit 4 images to each div

Comment: will i put this inside another loop?

Comment: no this will replace your current loop. this creates a new div tag after 4 images

Comment: i only got cols[0] and cols[4]

Comment: do you want col[1] and col[2]? i edited my answer to increment the column number by 1 in the div's

Comment: yeah it should be dynamic colums depends on the pic